# Solving the inequality $(\tan(4x)+\cot(4x)-\frac52)(\cos(2x)+|\sin(x)|)>0$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

$$\left(\tan(4x)+\cot(4x)-\frac52\right)\left(\cos(2x)+|\sin(x)|\right)>0$$ **Attempt.** So I know that the product $ab>0$ can be splitted onto $a>0$ and $b>0$ or $a<0$ and $b<0$. And I don't have an issue with $\tan(4x)+\cot(4x)-\frac52 >0$ but with the other one. So my main question remains on solving: $$\cos(2x)+|\sin(x)|>0$$ and I'll figure out how to solve with $<0$ but for now I want to focus on this. I've tried going through: $$\cos(2x)>-|\sin(x)|$$ $$-|\sin(x)|<\cos(2x)$$ and then $$-\cos(2x)<-\sin(x)<\cos(2x)$$ so we split this into 2 inequalities: $$\cos(2x)>\sin(x)\text{ and }-\sin(x)<\cos(2x)$$ but I realised that wolframalpha doesn't give me the same solutions with $-|\sin(x)|<\cos(2x)$ from $\cos(2x)>\sin(x)\text{ and }-\sin(x)<\cos(2x)$. But I'm pretty much stuck and I don't know if I have made a mistake already.

Comment: $-|\sin(x)|<\cos(2x)$ does not imply $-\cos(2x)<-\sin(x)<\cos(2x)$.

Answer (score 2):

From $-|\sin x| \lt \cos 2x$, you have $$|\sin x| \gt -\cos 2x $$ This is always true if $$\cos 2x \gt 0 \iff x \in ( -\pi/4 +n\pi, \pi/4 +n\pi )$$

But if $\cos(2x) \le 0 $, then the inequality is equivalent to the squared inequality, i.e. $$\sin^2x \gt \cos^22x \\ \sin^2x \gt (1-2\sin^2 x)^2 \\ s^2 \gt 1+4s^4-4s^2 \\ 4s^4 -5s^2 +1 \lt 0 \\ (s^2-1)(4s^2-1) \lt 0 $$ Why don’t you try to finish?

Comment: why will it be always true if $\cos(2x)>0$?

Comment: @Xetrez  $-\cos 2x \lt 0$ while $|\sin x| \ge 0$.

Comment: oh okay, and can you expand upon the part "if cos(2x)<=0, then the inequality is equivalent to the squared inequality"?

Comment: @Xetrez For $a\gt 0$, $|x| \gt a \iff x\gt a$ or $x\lt -a$. But these are exactly the conditions for $ x^2 \gt a^2$.

Comment: hm, not exactly getting that part, I mean I initially thought cos(2x)>0 would just straight give us all the solutions but are you suggesting that we also have to solve for $\sin^2(x)=\cos^2(2x)$ to get the rest of the solutions?

Comment: @Xetrez Yes, that doesn’t cover all of them.

Comment: okay but hmm, I'm still having issues understanding why we now have to consider that part

Comment: @Xetrez Ask yourself why you don’t  think that all possibilities should be considered.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123675/discussion-between-xetrez-and-tavish).

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

If $|\sin x|=a,$

$$\cos2x+|\sin x|=1-2a^2+a=\dfrac{9-(4a-1)^2}8$$

As $0\le a\le1,$ for real $a,$
$$\implies\dfrac98\ge\cos2x+|\sin x|\ge0$$

What if $\cos2x+|\sin x|=0?$

else we need $$\tan2x+\cot2x-\dfrac52>0$$